# Duplicacy Issue In PHP /MYsql

Tags: php, mysql, insert, refresh

I am inserting a row in mysql table. The row is getting inserted successfully in the table.
But the issues is that whenever I refresh the page, a new row is added in the database.

How to prevent it?

Comment: just block the user to refresh. forward to a new page after adding the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is browser's issue. They repost data on refresh. To prevent it from happening, you'll have to check for duplication of data in your code each time a new record is inserted. This is the general practice where duplication of data has to be prevented.

In another case where a genuine duplicate data is expected and allowed, what you can do is to redirect user on to the same registration page after each insertion by `header("Location: {$location}");`. This will clear the POST data of the browser.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

> Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) is a common design pattern for web developers to help avoid certain duplicate form submissions and allow user agents to behave more intuitively with bookmarks and the refresh button.

In PHP, this looks like so, generally...

```
<?php

handleForm($_POST);

header('Location: next-page.php');
exit;
```

Obviously `handleForm()` is to be substituted for your code that handles the inserts etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use primary key in mysql table. Make any column as primary key column